# Do something if a table exists

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to find out if there a table called `OOK` and if so, do something to it. This is what I have so far, which does not work with a helpful `ERROR 1064 […] syntax error` message:

```
IF show tables like 'OOK' THEN
    DELETE FROM OOK WHERE Id = 'Development';
    INSERT INTO OOK VALUES ( 'Development', 'Localhost' );
END IF
```

This is to support some legacy code and might not be the best solution to the problem. However, it will fix it for what I need.

Since I am getting lots of syntax errors on the answers, here is the exact version I have: `Server version: 5.5.60-MariaDB MariaDB Server`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access [Information Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html), to check if the table exists or not. Also, you will need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) (to handle the case when table name does not exist)

Try something like below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM information_schema.tables 
           WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name' 
           AND table_name = 'OOK') THEN 

  SET @s1 = 'DELETE FROM your_database_name.OOK WHERE Id = ?';
  SET @a = 'Development';
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
  EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

  SET @s2 = 'INSERT INTO your_database_name.OOK VALUES (?, ?)';
  SET @b = 'Development';
  SET @c = 'Localhost';
  PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s2;
  EXECUTE stmt1 USING @b, @c;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

END IF
```

Comment: Is that going to parse when `OOK` doesn't exist?

Comment: @Andrew good point. Now, I think again; it can be solved using Dynamic SQL

Comment: I get this: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 12: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 …`

Comment: @Sardathrion this code snippet will work inside a stored procedure. You cannot use it stand-alone

Answer (score 0):

I use the procedure and the function below in a table duplication process in a db:

## Usage

```
CALL do_something('mydb', 'OOK', 'Development', 'Development', 'Localhost');
```

## Implementation

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE do_something(
  IN dbName VARCHAR(255),
  IN tableName VARCHAR(255),
  IN id VARCHAR(255),
  IN value1 VARCHAR(255),
  IN value2 VARCHAR(255)
)
  BEGIN
    IF ( fn_table_exists(dbName, tableName) )
      THEN
        CALL statement(CONCAT(
          'DELETE FROM ', tableName, ' WHERE Id = "', id, '"'));
        CALL statement(CONCAT(
          'INSERT INTO ', tableName, ' VALUES ( "', value1, '", "', value2, '" )'));
      ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT(
          'ERROR: Table "', tableName, '" does not exist in the schema "', dbName, '".'
        ) AS ErrorMessage;
      END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE statement(IN dynamic_statement TEXT)
  BEGIN
      SET @dynamic_statement := dynamic_statement;
      PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @dynamic_statement;
      EXECUTE prepared_statement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE FUNCTION fn_table_exists(dbName VARCHAR(255), tableName VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS TINYINT(1)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE totalTablesCount INT DEFAULT (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM information_schema.TABLES
      WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA COLLATE utf8_general_ci = dbName COLLATE utf8_general_ci)
        AND (TABLE_NAME COLLATE utf8_general_ci = tableName COLLATE utf8_general_ci)
    );
    RETURN IF(
      totalTablesCount > 0,
      TRUE,
      FALSE
    );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I get `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12` which is the first `THEN` in `do_something`…

Comment: @Sardathrion At this time I am unable to test for MariaDB. I have InnoDB. Perhaps add opening and closing brackets to if, as in updated revision of this answer.

Comment: @Sardathrion Could you try replacing the body of `THEN` with `SELECT 1;` and see if the error is still thrown? I'd also verify that body of the IF block you've provided doesn't throw that error.

Comment: No change. I wonder if the error is because I am just running this file as SQL: `cat file.sql | mysql` type of things.

Comment: @Sardathrion Perhaps try with `DELIMITER`s with the latest revision?